# RingCentral Update Extension API Error: EXT-413: Credentials changing is not allowed

Tags: single-sign-on, settings, ringcentral

When calling the Update Extension API, I receive the error "Credentials changing is not allowed". What does this mean and how do I resolve this?

I'm setting the following properties:

- `status` to `Enabled`
- `ivrPin` to check voicemail on Polycom devices
- `password` to log into RingCentral apps

Here's info on the API:

- Update Extension API

  - https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-reference#User-Settings-updateExtension

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
{
  "status":400,
  "statusText":"Bad Request",
  "url":"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/11111111",
  "message":{
    "errorCode":"EXT-413",
    "message":"Credentials changing is not allowed",
    "errors":[
      {
        "errorCode":"EXT-413",
        "message":"Credentials changing is not allowed"
      }
    ]
  },
  "originalRequest":{
    "method":"PUT",
    "path":"/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/11111111"
  },
  "rcRequestId":[
    "11112222-3333-4444-5555-666677778888"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will be encountered when attempting to update a user's `password` when Single Sign-On (SSO) is enabled on the account and passwords are managed by an external Identity Provider (IdP).

When SSO is enabled, you can still update the `ivrPin` and `status` properties, but not the `password`.

More on RingCentral SSO is available here:

- Single Sign-On (SSO) - Overview

  - https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/6748